# My character just floats up into the sky

Tags: c#, unity, jumping

So this is the code I'm using for jumping. The character just floats in to the sky. I'm making an infinite runner.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

public float moveSpeed;
public float jumpForce;

private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0));
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity=new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    }
}
}
```

Edit:

Code to @Hamzan Hasan:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpForce;

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    //void Update () {
    //  myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);
    //
    //  if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0));
    //  {
    //      myRigidbody.velocity=new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    //  }
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0));
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    void Jump () {
        myRigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
        }


    }
```

Edit 3: The solution is in the chat below.

Comment: are you using mecanim?

Comment: @DoughnutZombie I don't have animation yet. It's just a sprite for now.

Comment: A sprite with rigidbody and boxcollider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0));
    {
        Jump();
    }
}

void Jump () {
    myRigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
}
```

As far as your horizontal movement is concern, you can set initial velocity with frictionless collider as,

```
void Start(){
    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);
}
```

Comment: And a suggestion for you, in any infinite runner game, do not move character itself, move platform instead.

Comment: Hazan http://i.imgur.com/iG0vWdS.png After the upper code the character doesn't move. I would also like for the character move, because I'm doing a tutorial, but this particular part doesn't work. It worked for him though.

Comment: even after  `myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);` in `Start()`?

Comment: It still stays in place and "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerControl.Jump () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerControl.cs:32)
PlayerControl.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerControl.cs:27)" error comes out. I updated what my script looks like now upthere.

Comment: Also another error: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerControl.Jump () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerControl.cs:32)
PlayerControl.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerControl.cs:27)".

Comment: You didn't assing `Rigidbody2D`, thats why, so before  `myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);` add `myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33363/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-sleepysleeper).

Comment: So when I play the project it flies up in a curve. Before it flied in a straight 45 degree turn.